# Как прикреплять к каждому пользователю в MySQL одну таблицу с правом ее изменять

Tags: mysql, sql, usercontrol

Хочу чтобы на каждого User в MySql создавался table с названием user'а 
Например создаю пользователя с именем John даю ему право Insert и Update для таблицы которая названа его именем куда он может вводить записи и изменять их

Comment: попробуйте глянуть здесь https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/mysql-ru

Comment: @Drakonoved не знаю как реализовать SQL запрос, а именно как создать таблицу чтобы потом пользователь мог делать записи только в ней